# Qt warning: passing qreal for converting QRect::QRect(int, int, int, int)

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, qt4

I am getting following warnings for code:

```
QRect rct ( 0, 0, rect().width(), rect().height() );

warning: passing `qreal' for converting 3 of `QRect::QRect(int, int, int, int)'
warning: passing `qreal' for converting 4 of `QRect::QRect(int, int, int, int)'
```

I googled it, but haven't found much. How to avoid this warning?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Why do you need that line? `rect()` of a `QWidget` should have `x` and `y` zero. Or what is `rect()`?

Comment: @LogicStuff, Thanks for reply, its used further in `QGradient g = QConicalGradient ( QPoint ( rct.center() ), -angle );` and `painter->drawEllipse ( rct );` to draw an gradient.

Comment: `QPoint(rct.center())` is another case of superfluous (possible) temporary copy-construction.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `rect()` returns a `QRectF`, and you want to convert it to `QRect`. You have two options:

- [`QRectF::toRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrectf.html#toRect) (discarded decimal part)
- [`QRectF::toAlignedRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrectf.html#toAlignedRect) (rounded).

Comment: I don't know why `rect().width()` and `rect().height()` was used, replacing it with `integer constant` solved the problem. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll have to ammend LogicStuff's reply. Our answers have different interpretation of the documentation so please check for yourselves, and I am happy to delete this if I am wrong.

It appears that rect() returns a QRectF, and you want to convert it to QRect. You have two options:

- [QRectF::toRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrectf.html#toRect) (rounded to nearest integer)
- [QRectF::toAlignedRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrectf.html#toAlignedRect) (Bounding box, smallest integer rectangle containing the desired QRectF).

## toRect

E.g. for precision drawing something that looks accurate

## toAlignedRect

E.g. for ensuring that you don't omit a line of pixels when drawing something.

For example, 1/3 in binary is `0.0101010101010101010101...`
so depending on how you calculate one and a half thirds, you may get a half, represented as either
`0.10000000000000000...` or `0.0111111111111...` and maybe round it up calculating one way and down calculating it another. It would then be unfortunate if you drew the edge of a feature (calculated one way) and neglected to erase a row of pixels when wiping the slate clear using a rectangle calculated another way. My calculation example may be wrong, but it's only meant to be illustrative.